# Getting Signature of SSL Certificate in PHP

Tags: php, openssl

I am looking for a solution to get the signature of a certificate from the base64_encoded certificate. From my understanding (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_key_certificate#Contents_of_a_typical_digital_certificate), the signature of a certificate is contained in the certificate itself. However, I haven't found a way to retrieve that signature.

I intend on using the signature to check the SSL certificate chain with openssl_verify(). I know it's possible to do via exec('openssl verify -CAfile root.pem certificate.pem '), but I want to know if there's a method of doing it within PHP itself even if it's slightly more complicated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

php is incredibly lacking in its native ability to handle security certificates but there are some libs out there that have been written and are pretty easy to use.  One of the best I found is xmlseclib.php at: [xmlseclib on google](http://code.google.com/p/xmlseclibs/)

Comment: Thanks. Will definitely look into it.

Answer (score 2):

You can do use [phpseclib, a pure PHP X509 implementation](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/x509/intro.html):

```
<?php
include('File/X509.php');

$x509 = new File_X509();
$cert = $x509->loadX509('...');

echo $cert['signature'];
```

Note that that sig will be base64-encoded. Depending on what you need it for you might want to base64_decode it.